# Deleted sources.list.d and sources.list in "/etc/apt" accidentally

Tags: apt, delete

While debugging some errors, I accidentally deleted **sources.list.d** and **sources.list** at "/etc/apt". Now, I cannot install or do anything just because those files do not exist.

How can I get those files back? Is there any way to recover them?

I have a copy of the context of the **sources.list**.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: By default the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory is empty, so restoration of that to default will be an empty directory.  Only you can know what you added, and so its contents need to come from your backups.

Answer (score 0):

First, recover your `source.list`. If you can remember where can you find the lists in `source.list.d`, download or copy lists then put them into `source.list.d`.